# Firefox Restartless Addon: Errors Logged on Enable/Disable

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-restartless

I have been testing and when a Bootstrapped/Restartless Addon is enabled or disabled, a number of errors are logged relating to other addons.

```
Duplicate resource declaration for 'specialpowers' ignored. chrome.manifest:32
Duplicate resource declaration for 'gre-resources' ignored. chrome.manifest:33
Duplicate resource declaration for 'services-sync' ignored. components.manifest:163
Duplicate resource declaration for 'services-common' ignored. components.manifest:165
Duplicate resource declaration for 'services-crypto' ignored. components.manifest:166
Could not read chrome manifest 'file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Mozilla%20Firefox/chrome.manifest'.
Duplicate resource declaration for 'pdf.js' ignored. pdfjs.manifest:1
Duplicate resource declaration for 'lazarus' ignored. chrome.manifest:49
Duplicate resource declaration for 'clippings' ignored. chrome.manifest:9
Duplicate resource declaration for 'greasemonkey' ignored. chrome.manifest:15
Duplicate resource declaration for 'dwhelper' ignored. chrome.manifest:75
Duplicate resource declaration for 'xnotifier' ignored. chrome.manifest:105
Duplicate resource declaration for 'urlmulticopy' ignored. chrome.manifest:7
Duplicate resource declaration for 'textmulticopy' ignored. chrome.manifest:7
Duplicate resource declaration for 'imdbplus' ignored. chrome.manifest:9
Duplicate resource declaration for 'rpnethelper' ignored.  chrome.manifest:9
```

On enabling the restartless addon:

```
Could not read chrome manifest 'file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Mozilla%20Firefox/browser/extensions/%7B972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd%7D/chrome.manifest'.
1403891812867   Services.Metrics.Provider.org.mozilla.addons    WARN    Add-on type without field: dictionary

1403891812867   Services.Metrics.Provider.org.mozilla.addons    WARN    Add-on type without field: userstyle

1403891812867   Services.Metrics.Provider.org.mozilla.addons    WARN    Add-on type without field: greasemonkey-user-script

No chrome package registered for chrome://dta-modules/content/support/filtermanager.js
Invalid URI. Load of media resource  failed. browser.xul
1403891888204   Services.Metrics.Provider.org.mozilla.addons    WARN    Add-on type without field: dictionary

1403891888205   Services.Metrics.Provider.org.mozilla.addons    WARN    Add-on type without field: userstyle

1403891888205   Services.Metrics.Provider.org.mozilla.addons    WARN    Add-on type without field: greasemonkey-user-script
```

I have tried different Restartless addon and all log similar errors (from other sources) on enable/disable. The errors do not appear to affect the operation of Firefox or the addons.

What are these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What are these?

Noise. Really, disregard all of those.

- Those "Duplicate Resource" warnings are due to the way Firefox (re-)loads manifests.
- "Could not read chrome manifest" in the installation directory is because the platform supports having a manifest in the installation directory but Firefox doesn't use this capability (anymore).
- The `Service.Metrics.Provider` ones are related to the performance metrics Firefox collects and may send to mozilla if you opted-in. That thing doesn't really know how to deal with certain add-on types, and hence the warnings.
- The `972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd` manifest warning is the default theme. I didn't even know it is still around. Probably a left-over from installing Firefox back when and upgrading afterwards.
- And then there is something trying to load a DownThemAll! 3.0 file, which isn't present.

Comment: I knew there were not that important...but they shouldn't happen nonetheless ;) I haven't had DownThemAll! for a long while (it is yours, I know). There seem to be a lot of leftover bits. Although restartless addons have been around since Firefox 4, it seems there isnt a robust framework in place yet for Mozilla and addon developers.